# How can i change the order of waypoints in the array according to the object facing rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

At the top of the script:

```
public Transform traveller;
public GameObject[] waypoints;
public Transform nextWaypoint;
public bool reverse = false;
private int targetsIndex = 0;
```

In Start:

```
void Start()
    {
        waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Waypoint").OrderBy(go => go.name).ToArray();
        targetsIndex = 0;       
   }
```

In Update:

```
void Update()
    {
        WayPointsAI();
    }
```

Then WayPointsAI:

```
private void WayPointsAI()
    {
        if (targetsIndex == waypoints.Length)
            targetsIndex = 0;

        nextWaypoint = waypoints[targetsIndex].transform;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(traveller.transform.position, nextWaypoint.transform.position);
        traveller.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(traveller.transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(nextWaypoint.position - traveller.transform.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (reverse == true)
        {
            var targetAngles = traveller.transform.eulerAngles + 180f * Vector3.up;
            traveller.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(traveller.transform.eulerAngles, targetAngles, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            var lastWaypoint = waypoints[currentIndex];

        }

        if (distance < distancetoRotate)
        {
            traveller.transform.position += traveller.transform.forward * slowDownSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            traveller.transform.position += traveller.transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (distance < nextWaypoint.transform.localScale.magnitude)
        {
            rotateNumber = true;
            currentIndex = targetsIndex;

            if (random == false)
            {
                targetsIndex++;
            }
            else
            {
                targetsIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, waypoints.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```

And the relevant part is the reverse:

```
if (reverse == true)
        {
            var targetAngles = traveller.transform.eulerAngles + 180f * Vector3.up;
            traveller.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(traveller.transform.eulerAngles, targetAngles, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            var lastWaypoint = waypoints[currentIndex];

        }
```

When i check the checkbox on reverse it will get to this part.

Now for example let's say the last waypoint the object visited was waypoint 1 (currentIndex = 1)

Now the object make u turn of 180 degrees facing the other way now i want him to keep moving to the other way but between the waypoints just the opposite direction.

The problem is how to change the waypoints array order. If for example last waypoint the object visited was 1 now he make a u turn should go back to 1 then to 0 then to 4 3 2 1 0 and so on.

So in any place i check the checkbox on reverse it should change the order of the waypoints array. This is what i can't figure how to do.
It should be in the reverse part after the line:

```
var lastWaypoint = waypoints[currentIndex];
```

Comment: assuming your index is sequential, waypoints[currentIndex > 0 ? currentIndex -1 : 0];  But in reality you should just be reversing the enumerable, but it seems you want to use indexers

Comment: The solution is seems to be by adding this two lines to the reverse part: Array.Reverse(waypoints);
            reverse = false; The first one reverse the array order the second to prevent from it to keep reversing non stop since reverse is true all the time/ Anyway this is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be better approached by splitting up the task more logically.

Create a field that's the target waypoint

I'd recommend  making a function that's "headtowaypoint" that's in charge of ONLY heading towards the target waypoint.

Then, have another function that deals with what happens AT a waypoint, this will call a function setnextwaypoint,

and then have another function that is "reverse" which sets a bool that heads towards the last waypoint, and tells setnextwaypoint that you're going to the previous one, and tells headtowaypoint that you're now going down rather than up the list.